# How to keep the record whether a checkbox has been checked or not?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a sports list in a mobile app with Ionic, there is a view where the user choose(check) which sports would like to see on the list

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="sport.checked"
       ng-init="sport.checked=true">
```

and then once he chooses the sports, he goes to the other view

```
<div ng-repeat="sport in sports">
    <div ng-show="sport.checked">

      {{sport.name}}

    </div>
</div>
```

but if the user refresh the page or go to any other view and tries to get back to the sports view, he loses the selections of sports he just did, so he needs to perform the action of selecting again which sports he wants to see.

[I recorded this video for you to understand easier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFzhTHiNCps&feature=youtu.be)

on the video you will see that I go to the view and unchecked the first two sports on the list, they disappear but once I refresh the page, those 2 sports will be on the list again.

Maybe the issue is the `ng-init` so I want you to tell me guys what I need to do to keep the record of which sports he selects ?

**UPDATE**

base on your answer, look at my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('SportsController', function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading,
                                           $timeout, AuthFactory, SportsFactory) {
    $scope.sports = [];
    $scope.customer = {};

    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
      $scope.customer = customer;
      SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        if (sports.length) {
          $scope.sports = sports;
        }else {
          AuthFactory.logout();
        }

      }, function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
      });
    }, function(err) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $state.go('app.login');
      console.log(err);
    });

    $scope.isSportShown = function(sport) {
      return $scope.shownSport === sport;
    };

    $scope.goToLines = function(league) {
      var linesParameters = {
        customerId: $scope.customer.customer,
        top: 10,
        familyGameId: -1,
        games: -1,
        sports: league.sport.id,
        leagues: league.id,
        periods: league.lineType,
        part: league.part
      };
      $state.transitionTo('app.lines', linesParameters);
    };
  });
```

Comment: You can use a service to keep the selection between views. If you restart the app, then the selection needs to be in a more persistent storage

Comment: The canonical way to solve this problem is to use routing in order to make the URL reflect the UI state; reloading the page would give you back to the same state in this case.

Comment: can you give a little code example of what I need to do ? you both @PauloScardine

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I suspect your question (as currently stated) is a bit too broad for this format or has too many good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything that happens in the browser will be lost when the page is closed/refreshed, unless it is persisted either into a database, or for a simple case like this one you could use the local storage.

To get the idea, you could do something likle this:

```
<input type="checkbox"
   ng-model="sport.checked"
   ng-change="save(sport.checked)"
   ng-init="sport.checked = CONFIG.sport">
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.CONFIG = localStorage.getItem('CONFIG');
if (!$scope.CONFIG) {
  $scope.CONFIG = {sport: true};
}

$scope.save = function(checked) {
  $scope.CONGIF.sport = checked;
  localStorage.setItem('CONFIG', $scope.CONFIG);
}
```

Basically when the user check, you store that into the localStorage (here using a  `CONFIG` variable, but it could be anything). Then on page initialization, you read the value of the localStorage.

localStorage is just a temporary storage into the browser itself: if the user swktches browser or use another computer he will not see his persisted data. If you want to do that it needs to be persisted server side via some database.

Comment: I am getting an error ```TypeError: Cannot set property 'sport' of undefined``` look at my controller, I just update my question.

Comment: That's because you didn't initalize `$scope.CONFIG` first as I do in my `if` expression. I just gave you a generic solution using localStorage, you may need to adapt it to your needs.